# Laravel 5.4 implicit route model binding with resource returns empty object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm stuck on a very odd issue with laravel's route model binding.

Using a route resource:

```
Route::resource('vendors', 'VendorController');
```

The route for editing an entry is the following:

```
GET|HEAD | admin/vendors/{vendor}/edit | vendors.edit | App\Http\Controllers\VendorController@edit | web,auth.admin
```

So from my understanding of implicit route model binding, the vendor attribute should allow accessing the object directly.

In my Controller function I can get the actual id with no problem. But when I try to get the vendor object, the result is empty. No 404, but just an empty result, making the template fail with "Undefined variable: vendor".

```
public function edit(Vendor $vendor)
{
    dd($vendor);
    return view('admin.vendor.edit', compact($vendor));
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Update: For some reason the route model binding is now working. However the template still throws an error, saying vendor is undefined.

```
@extends('admin.layout')

@section('content')

{!! Form::model($vendor, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'url' => 'admin/vendors'.$vendor->id]) !!}
    @include ('admin.vendor._form', ["submitButtonText" => "Änderungen speichern"])
{!! Form::close() !!}

@include ('_errors')

@endsection
```

Comment: I believe it's because {vendor} is the ID of the vendor object.

You'd have to use that ID to get the object from the DB.

Comment: If you don't type hint it (i.e. `function edit($vendor)`), what do you get when you `dd()`? Assuming it's the ID, what do you get when you `Vendor::find($vendor)`?

Comment: Are you correctly importing your App\Vendor model into your controller?

Comment: App\Vendor is imported. For some reason it now does return an object as it should. But my template is still failing.

Comment: Your template is likely failing because that's not how you use compact.  Try `compact('vendor')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return view('admin.vendor.edit', compact($vendor));
```

to this:

```
return view('admin.vendor.edit', compact('vendor'));
```

Comment: Per route model binding returning empty model see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13988

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because {vendor} is the ID of the vendor object.

You'd have to get that object using that ID I believe.

Something like this:

```
Vendor::find($vendor);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to *compacting* an array, you could:

```
public function edit(Vendor $vendor)
{
   return view('admin.vendor.edit')->withVendor($vendor);
}
```