# Laravel 5.5 Object to update lost when passing from view to update method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm getting mad trying to update a simple entity, I've seen that when I change the parameter `Role $role` to int `$id` of my update method and make a `findOrFail` before updating, it works but it seems that my blade `for::open` doesn't pass my object `$role` to my controller.
I've tried to pass it like this in my edit blade template :

```
{{ Form::open(['name'=>'editrole','method'=> 'put','route'=>['Role.update',$role],
                    'class'=>'mt-4 ml-2']) }}
```

or like this :

```
{{ Form::open(['name'=>'editrole','method'=> 'put','url'=>route('Role.update',$role),
                    'class'=>'mt-4 ml-2']) }}
```

Here id the update method :

```
public function update(RoleRequest $request, Role $role)
{

    try{

        //dd($role);
        $role->update($request->all());
        return redirect(route('Role.index'))->with('success_message','Rôle modifié');

    }catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex){

        return redirect(route('Role.index'))->with('error_message',
            'Erreur : '.$ex->getMessage().'<br />'.$ex->getTraceAsString());

    }

}
```

when making a `dd($role)` in update method attributes are empty
Thanks for your help.

The route is like this :

```
// Gestion des rôles
Route::resource('Role','Admin\RoleController');
```

Comment: Share your route for this?

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass the object as a route parameter. Use the id as you said, then set the object attributes in individual form fields.

You don t need the try catch because the 404 will occur before it reaches your method if the route model binding fails.

```
public function update(RoleRequest $request, Role $role) {
    $role->update($request->all());
    return redirect(route('Role.index'))->with('success_message','Rôle modifié');
}
```

Edit:

It's all explained in the Implicit Binding section:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Ok it's weird because when you generate the controlers by default they accept a model object in update methods and the blade documentation seems to say it's possible

Comment: The controller methods have a model object due to route model binding. Laravel does a `find` behind the scenes for you based on the id and route definition.

Comment: So I must change my method parameter and make a findOrFail before ?

Comment: No that's all ok as it is, change your forms action to `route('Role.update',$role->id)`

Comment: It changes nothing and the dd of $role have always empty attributes

Comment: Check your Kernel.php and make sure `SubstituteBindings` middleware is registered.

Comment: And you are using the web middleware group for this route?

Comment: the route is in this route group :
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware' => ['role:Admin|direction']], function () {

Comment: Ah looks like you're not applying the SubstituteBindings to the route. Try this `['web', 'role:Admin|direction']]`

Comment: no, same problem... And I don't think my RoleRequest is involved in this problem.

Comment: I also checked the fillable attributes in the model

Comment: What does network inspector show for the request? Does it contain the expected payload? Url look correct? Something isnt adding up here .

Comment: No it seems correct  the values in headers are _method:PUT
_token:IsEBvcNGvqB3wGNCMLJU4x4s5ga5e7Gu4G2zSTm8
name:direction
description:Groupe des membres de la directionn and url is http://vuelaravel/admin/Role/3

Comment: It seems to be an issue related to the route resource binding, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633286/laravel-5-4-implicit-route-model-binding-with-resource-returns-empty-object